# no /etc/default/portmap file in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: services

My computer running Pop!_OS 20.04 (basically Ubuntu 20.04 with some additions) doesn't have a portmap file to resolve port numbers to service names. I did a

```
sudo apt install portmap
```

which installed a port mapper, but still, there is no corresponding file. Therefore, I cannot get service names when I run netstat.

How can I add, fill, and otherwise edit a portmap file? Or is there some other system in 20.04?

Thank you for your kind assistance,

M

Comment: According to the man page, netstat uses /etc/services for services translation

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)